# Is there a name for this simple identity verification scheme?

Tags: hash, signature, protocol-design, hash-signature

Once, while idly wondering, I came up with a simple scheme to prove the authenticity of a chain of messages given the authenticity of the first.

It consists of putting a hash at the end of each message (but the last, if you know where the chain is going to end) and the input to the previous hash at the beginning (or anywhere really) of each subsequent message.

That's it. It's really simple but I was wondering if it had a name?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. For database security, similar ideas were proposed, like chained circular hashes, etc. I don't know/remember a well-known name for that.

Comment: Normally you'd use a Merkle tree or hash list for that, which has the benefit of being able to hash the data in any order and possibly in parallel (if you cache the results), while preserving the order in the tree. If you want to add an authentication tag or two in there the idea should still work.